# Reading integers with commas between them

Tags: c, strtok

I assumed using **strtok** would be best because of the formatting of the input.
But I've run into a few problems when trying to detect errors:

an example of a line the program would read:

```
 .data 123,456,89 
 .data     12,   34,   53   ,   64
```

these are all ok.

My problem is when the input is incorrect, for example:

```
 .data 200 4000 // no comma speration
 .data 1, ,3 // ,3 should be an error
 .data 4, // the extra , should be an error
 .data 12.2 // the .2 should be an error
 and so on
```

My code (SIZE is for buffer size = 30, valid_num goes through the token to see if all the chars are numbers), the idea was to first check the validity of the tokens and add them to a buffer, if all numbers are valid, add the numbers to my data base:

```
 while((sptr = strtok(NULL, ", \t\n")) != NULL){ //this is after reading using strtok before.
    if(i < SIZE && valid_num(sptr)){ //buffer is not full and the token contains only numbers
        temp_num = atoi(sptr);
        if(temp_num >= MIN_VAL && temp_num <= MAX_VAL){ //number is within the required size
            buffer[i] = temp_num; /*fill buffer*/
            i++;
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "(%d) Error: %d is out of bounds. Valid numbers are between %d and %d\n", line_count, temp_num, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL);
        }
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d) Error: %s is not a valid number\n",line_count, sptr);
    }
    tok_count++;
}

if(i == tok_count){ //if all tokens were read correctly, add the data to database.
    DC += add_data(buffer, tok_count, DC, data_Table);
}
else{
    if(sptr != NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "(%d) Error: %s is not a digit, .data can only be used for integers\n", line_count, sptr);
    }

}
```

Should I try to do the same but with **sscanf**, even though the length of the input is unknown?

How can I enforce a certain pattern? number - comma - number ...

Perhaps using a few different **strtok** inside the loop?

Comment: So... you wanna attempt to parse invalid input? Why? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Might work better if you used `strpbrk` as that way you can see what the dividing character is and act aqccordingly?

Comment: either parse it and then throw an error or avoid parsing it all together

Comment: haven't heard of strsep, looking into it now.

Comment: @Immanuel ignore that - I meant `strpbrk`

Comment: Robust parsing of lists of numbers is hard, especially if you don't know how many the list contains. Generally you write a fiddly bit of code on top of strtod(), and search for the separating commas in the main loop.

Comment: Consider using `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` to parse substrings into numbers.  One of the key advantages of the former is that it allows you to determine how much, if any, of the input was converted.

Comment: +1 for @JohnBollinger's comment, and just to add that `strtol` can become almost a drop-in replacement for `strtok`, because it allows you to iterate through a string and pull numbers out.  The only logic you'd need to add is something that eats whitespace, and then if a comma was found to expect the next call to `strtol` to find something.  Anything that's not a comma or whitespace would be an error.

Comment: `scanf` and even all the strxxx functions can only build a poor man's parser. It will be fine to  process syntactically correct data, but if you want to be able to raise relevant error messages, you should considere either building a parser *by hand* (loop processing one char at a time) if the problem is simple enough or use the good old lex+yacc (or flex+bison) to build a robust parser.

Comment: What is the minimum `int` per line? 0 or 1 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways to parse the line.

OP's `temp_num = atoi(sptr);` does not detect overflow as 1) overflow with `atoi()` is undefined and 2) there is no error return value.

---

I believe the below will cope with all hostile input.  It does not use `strtok()`, but `strtol()` to find non-numeric input.

Making use of helper functions provides clarity of each step.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void consume_whitespace(char **input) {
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) **input))
    (*input)++;
}

int parse_int(char **input, int *dest) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long y = strtol(*input, &endptr, 10);
  if (*input == endptr) return -1; // no conversion
  if (errno) return -1;  // overflow
  #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
    if (y < INT_MIN || y > INT_MAX) return -1;  // overflow
  #endif
  *input = endptr;
  *dest = (int) y;
  return 0;
}

int parse_data_line(char *input, const char *prefix, int *dest, int n) {
  size_t prefix_length = strlen(prefix);
  if (memcmp(input, prefix, prefix_length)) return -1;
  input += prefix_length;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    consume_whitespace(&input);
    if (*input == '\0') break;
    if (i > 0 && *input++ != ',') return -1;
    if (parse_int(&input, &dest[i])) return -1;
  }
  consume_whitespace(&input);
  if (*input) return -1;  // extra text
  return i;
}
```

Example usage

```
#define SIZE 30
int main() {
  int numbers[SIZE];
  char *input = foo();
  int count = parse_data_line(input, ".data", numbers, SIZE);
  if (count < 0) puts("Fail");
  else bar(numbers, count);
}
```